# Can you return@label some value in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I just learned about labeled returns in kotlin, and wrote this code example where I have a lambda passed to `with`, and there's another lambda passed to `forEach` and I tried to return out of `with` inside `forEach`, for some reason the compiler crashes, here's the code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) : Unit {
    val l = listOf(listOf(1,2,3), listOf(4,5,6))
    val t = label@ with(l) {
        get(0).forEach {
            return@label 2
        }
    }
    println(t)
}
```

Should this be allowed in Kotlin at all? Is this a compiler bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if you just want to return from the `with` you should rather use `return@with` instead.

So your code should rather look like:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) : Unit {
  val l = listOf(listOf(1,2,3), listOf(4,5,6))
  val t = with(l) {
    get(0).forEach {
      return@with 2
    }
  }
  println(t)
}
```

and yes... it will return `2` then.. You could also use `return@forEach` if you just wanted to return from the `forEach`...

If you really want to use your own label instead, ensure that you place it before the opening curly brace (without space (see also [Kotlin coding convention regarding lambda formatting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#lambda-formatting))), e.g.:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) : Unit {
  val l = listOf(listOf(1,2,3), listOf(4,5,6))
  val t = with(l) label@{
    get(0).forEach {
      return@label 2
    }
  }
  println(t)
}
```

Note also: if it were a `for`, `while`, or anything where `continue` or `break` can be used, then you actually place the label in front (see [Kotlin reference # Break and Continue Labels](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#break-and-continue-labels)), e.g.:

```
lambda@ for (i in 1..3) { 
  break@label
}
```

Finally: try to omit own labels whenever possible. Most of the time you do not really need them... and probably it already suffices to reuse existing return@labels. Check also the [Kotlin coding conventions, e.g. returns in lambda](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#returns-in-a-lambda)

Comment: I wonder why the compiler spits out such a large message and the IDE doesn't say anything, I felt like I was using C++ and got a template error message, lol. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, nvm, it says "Backend Internal error", meaning something crashed

Comment: well... the IDE (at least Intellij) doesn't really say that it's placed on the wrong side (which would also a bit much to know), it rather says that it's redundant, because it can't be referenced in either break, continue or return... ... well... I think that isn't that much clearer ;-)

Comment: just rechecked and yes, I also got a backend internal error... but as I use EAP most of the time and there often popped up some errors, which seemed to be plugin related I tend to ignore them...

Comment: There's a bug for this in youtrack, it hasn't been fixed yet